# Mysql group/ordering

Tags: mysql, grouping

i have a student management system for my martial arts club, 
different types of info are stored in different DB tables,

for attendance, and gradings a NEW row is added for each new event.

I am trying to get the information from students table and list total lessons attended from the attendance table, find their current grade information from the grading table
and order this by the order set in the grades_list table.

So i have this:

```
SELECT * , COUNT( date ) AS `count` 
  FROM attendance a
    JOIN students s ON a.student_id = s.student_id
    JOIN gradings g ON g.student_id = s.student_id
    JOIN grades_list gl ON gl.grade = g.grade
      WHERE s.class <>'Little Monsters'
        AND date
        BETWEEN'2013-01-01'
        AND now() 
          GROUP BY a.student_id
          ORDER BY gl.ID
```

This currently does the right sort of thing, but it's not showing ALL of the results, and if there are more than one entry for each persons grade (which there will be eventually) it shows one result but not the latest. I currently have two people in the gradings table with two entries each, one of those people is not shown at all the other one it shows their oldest record it should show the newest.

Hope that all makes sense.

Cheers.

Comment: Add a `GROUP_CONCAT()` to the many part of the 1:n relationship (attendance/gradings?) and `explode` the result later. (Or don't `GROUP BY` at all and you'll get duplicate `student_id`'s.) Additional notes: You could denormalize the `attendance` and `gradings` tables into one table if they have strict 1:1 relationship with `NOT NULL` constraints. And also `grades_list` seem like a small lookup table. Is it really needed in the query or at all?

Comment: Bit confused by some of those terms , so im going to go a look them up now.. 
The grades_list is there to set the order its displayed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you `GROUP BY a.student_id`, each student will be shown no more than once.
2. The records may disappear because of joins you do. If student is not present in `grades_list`, there is nothing to join on, so record won't be shown. You probably would want to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: ah that makes sense, the only thing in the grades_list is the grade colour & id. Il give it a go. thanks for ythe quick reply !

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the information from students table and list total lessons attended from the attendance table, find their current grade information from the grading table and order this by the order set in the grades_list table.
>
> –––if there are more than one entry for each persons grade (which there will be eventually)–––

The latter let me to think you maybe should redesing the DB. Lose the `grades` table. It's my belief student can have only one grade at any given time so make it an attribute of a student. Now you really need is a 1:n relationship between `student` and `attendance`. And you order students by `student.grade`. (Those students that attended a certain event.)

If you want to record history of students grade you could add a column `grade_when_attended` into `attendance` table. Or make a dedicated `grade_history` table:

- `student_id`, PK, FK to `student_id`
- `grade`, PK, FK to `grade_list`
- `date_when_earned`, `date`
- ...(?)

I'd prefer the "full" grade history approach but that would make the ordering students by grade of an attendenece event a little bit more complicated.

Possible query, simplified (lets think about ordering by grade etc. later if this works):

```
SELECT s.* , GROUP_CONCAT(a.column1), GROUP_CONCAT(a.column1)
  FROM students s
  LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.student_id = s.student_id
  WHERE s.class <>'Little Monsters'
    AND date
    BETWEEN'2013-01-01'
    AND now() 
      GROUP BY s.student_id
```

Query above shows only current grade so things could get messy if a new grade is earned during specified time period. (Quick and dirty solution would be to add the `grade_when_attended` column into `attendance` table so you'd get current grade and every grade per attendance during time period.)

Remember that you need to `GROUP_CONCAT` every column separately:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I think i may have found an easier way to work around this, like you have mentioned previously by adding grade on students table.
although i am trying to search at who is ready to grade, 
On that query i used BETWEEN'2013-01-01'
    AND now() 

i jst used that date to make life easier to begin with, ideally that would be their last grading date. 
if i add a column to students for last_grading is there a way i can 
use WHERE date BETWEEN s.last_grading AND now() 
???

Comment: @aaron Not sure what you mean but I guess no. If you have only one column `last_grading` and use the query above you select all of students with any given `last_grading`. If you are interested students who have earned (or participated) a grading event after 2013-01-01 use: `WHERE date > '2013-01-01'`. Note: you shouldn't have future dates in the table or you'll get odd results. To eliminate future dates use `WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND NOW()` (It's odd to have future dates for recorded events anyway. But you could have a future date for column like `next_possible_grading_event`).

Comment: Obviously above `date` should be `s.last_grading`. And this would list the students who have earned a grade during 2012: `WHERE s.last_grading BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'`.

Comment: Hiya
Thanks for your patience. 
What I mean is I have their last grading date in s.last_grading
Then I want to count total attendance between last_grading and now() (number of rows stored in attendance for that Id)
Cheers

Comment: @aaron Yes, if you have two tables: `student` (with `id`, and `last_granding`) and `attendance` (with `id`, `student` FK to student.id, `date_of_attendance`) you can do: `SELECT s.*, COUNT(a.id) FROM student s LEFT JOIN attendance a ON s.id = a.student WHERE a.date_of_attendance` > s.last_grading GROUP BY a.student`. No need to use `WHERE a.date_of_attendance BETWEEN s.last_grading AND CURDATE()` although both versions work just fine if `date_of_attendance` doesn't contain future dates.